# Jquery validate form submits with invalid fields and gets saved to database

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to set some server-side validation using the jquery validate plugin, but i am having a problem and can't seem to find what's wrong with my code. Using the form it passes and saves the data to the database even with invalid or missing fields. The frontend client side validation from the html is working fine, but not the backend. Here is the JsFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/y7fmb7m1/3/
PHP:

```
<?php
/**
 * Start the session.
 */
session_start();

/**
 * Include ircmaxell's password_compat library.
 */
require 'lib/password.php';

/**
 * Include our MySQL connection.
 */
require 'connect.php';


//If the POST var "register" exists (our submit button), then we can
//assume that the user has submitted the registration form.
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $form = $_POST;
    $username = $form['username'];
    $password = $form['password'];
    $firstName = $form['firstName'];
    $lastName = $form['lastName'];
    $address = $form['address'];
    $email = $form['email'];
    $age = $form['age'];
    $phone = $form['phone'];
//Retrieve the field values from our registration form.
    $username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : null;
    $pass = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;

//TO ADD: Error checking (username characters, password length, etc).
//Basically, you will need to add your own error checking BEFORE
//the prepared statement is built and executed.

//Now, we need to check if the supplied username already exists.

//Construct the SQL statement and prepare it.
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(username) AS num FROM users WHERE username = :username";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

//Bind the provided username to our prepared statement.
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);

//Execute.
    $stmt->execute();

//Fetch the row.
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//If the provided username already exists - display error.
//TO ADD - Your own method of handling this error. For example purposes,
//I'm just going to kill the script completely, as error handling is outside
//the scope of this tutorial.
    if ($row['num'] > 0) {
        die('That username already exists!');
    }

//Hash the password as we do NOT want to store our passwords in plain text.
    $passwordHash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 12));

//Prepare our INSERT statement.
//Remember: We are inserting a new row into our users table.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, phone, address, first_name, last_name, age) 
VALUES (:username, :password,:email, :phone, :address, :first_name, :last_name, :age)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

//Bind our variables.
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $stmt->bindValue(':password', $passwordHash);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $stmt->bindValue(':phone', $phone);
    $stmt->bindValue(':address', $address);
    $stmt->bindValue(':first_name', $firstName);
    $stmt->bindValue(':last_name', $lastName);
    $stmt->bindValue(':age', $age);

//Execute the statement and insert the new account.
    $result = $stmt->execute();

//If the signup process is successful.
    if ($result) {
        echo 'Thank you for registering with our website.';
        header('Location: login.php');

    }

}

?>
```

The Html:

```
<form id="registration">
            <fieldset>
                <legend class="extraPlace">Register</legend>
                <div class="input-group margin col-lg-6">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username *"
                           maxlength="8" minlength="4" required>

                </div>

                <div class="input-group margin">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password *"
                           maxlength="15" minlength="8" required>

                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" id="confirmPass" name="confirmPass" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password *" required>

                </div>

                <div class="input-group margin">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name *" required>

                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name *" required>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group margin col-lg-6">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email *" required>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group margin col-lg-6">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="Phone Number *" required>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group margin col-lg-6">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" id="address" name="address" type="text" placeholder="Address *" required>
                </div>

                <div class="input-group margin col-lg-6">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" id="age" name="age" type="number" placeholder="Age *" min="18" required>
                </div>

                <div class="checkbox alignLeftContent">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="agreement" id="agreement" value="1" > I have read and agree to the <a
                                href="https://www.un.org/Depts/ptd/terms-and-conditions-agreement">Terms and Conditions
                            *</a>
                    </label><br>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="gdpr" id="gdpr" value="1" > GDPR Agreement *
                    </label>
                    <div class="margin"><span>* &nbsp;&nbsp; Mandatory fields</span></div>
                </div>

                <input id="register_submit" class="btn btn-success " type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.validator.addMethod('strongPass', function(value, element){
                return this.optional(element) || value.length >= 8 && value.length <= 15;
        }, 'Your password must be between 8 and 15 characters');

        $('#registration').validate({
            rules: {
                firstName: {
                    required: true
                },

                lastName: {
                    required: true
                },

                age: {
                    required: true
                },

                address: {
                    required: true
                },

                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },

                password: {
                    required: true,
                    strongPass: true
                },

                confirmPass: {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: "#password"
                },

                username: {
                    alphanumeric: true,
                    length: {
                        minimum: 4,
                        maximum: 8
                    }

                },

                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    length: {
                        minimum: 10,
                        maximum: 10
                    }
                }

            },
            messages: {
                username: {
                    alphanumeric: "Cannot contain special symbols",
                    length: {
                        minimum: "At least 4 symbols required",
                        maximum: "No more than 8 symbols allowed"
                    }

                },
                firstName: "Please enter your firstname",
                lastName: "Please enter your lastname",
                age: "Please enter your age",
                phone: "Pleae enter your phone",
                address: "Please enter your address",
                password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password"
                },
                email:{
                    required: "Please enter an email address",
                    email: "Please enter a <i>valid email</i> address"
                }


            },

            submitHandler: function (form) {
                $(form).submit();

            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: Have you check the data received at your server ?

Comment: Do you get any errors in dev tools? Your jsfiddle doesn't have the validate plugin, so it will not work. And you didn't set jQuery as one of the frameworks used. Also, JavaScript (at least in this case) is not backend.  Backend code would be PHP, for example (sometimes JS if it's running on the server).  So, both validation methods you're using (HTML5 and JavaScript) are front-end validation. Either way, if you have errors, please post them.

Comment: this code working fine, to save data DB u must send data, with the validation plugin u can't send invalid data.
maybe you have other attached submit handlers?

Comment: I have a php code, edited my post to add it, thanks.